# Retrieving attribute from hdf5 files using python

Tags: attributes, hdf5, h5py

I want to retrieve a string from an attributes in a hdf5 file using Python 3.

It has a 'b' in front in addition to quotation marks. How can I remove the b and quotation marks

```py
import h5py
f = h5py.File('.../HS-L1C-FA-166db-00.hdf5', 'r')
aq_time=f['LEVEL1C']['VNIR0'].attrs['TIMESTAMP']


>>> aq_time
b'2018-11-01T11:43:55Z'
>>> aq_time[2:]
b'18-11-01T11:43:55Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

All strings in HDF5 are encoded text, so you need to decode.
It's easy to add:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('.../HS-L1C-FA-166db-00.hdf5', 'r')
aq_time=f['LEVEL1C']['VNIR0'].attrs['TIMESTAMP'].decode('utf-8')
```

More info about HDF5 strings in h5py docs here:
http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html